# Progress counter Page Method call is aborted

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a fairly long process running in a standard postback.  Then I have the following page method to return progress to a repeating JavaScript function that is supposed to report on progress.

My simple page method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int GetProgress()
{
    return (int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["ActivationResources.ImportProgress"] ?? 0);
}
```

My clientside script:

```
function startProgress() {
    window.setInterval(updateImportProgress(), 500);
}

var importProgress = 0;
function updateImportProgress() {
    //debugger;
    PageMethods.GetProgress(function (result, response, context) {
        if (result == importProgress) {
            $("#messageLabel").append(" .");
        }
        else {
            $("#messageLabel").html("Busy importing resources - " + result + "%");
        }
        importProgress = result;
    });
}
```

The `updateImportProgress` function is called, but Firebug reports that the POST for GetProgress is 'aborted'.  Why could this be?  I suspect that this is because the call to the static method is blocked by the actual executing method whose progress I am trying to monitor.  A breakpoint in the `GetProgress` method is never hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before. As a workaround I've implemented the code in an ashx file and avoided that way to touch the same page. Should work for your code as well, as you simply report a session variable.

Btw, note that your code breaks when you have 2 requests running in a single session. That can happen when you open multiple tabs of the same page in the browser.